# Excel VBA function giving "Argument not Optional"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBA function for converting Declination & Right Ascension to their decimal values.

I have a perfectly working function for the RA but keep getting an

> Argument not Optional

error.

The function is currently:

```
Public Function dec2decimal(Deg As Integer, Min2 As Integer, Sec2 As Integer) As Double

    Dim Dec As Double
    Dec = 0
    If Deg >= 0 Then
        Dec = (Deg + Min2 / 60 + Sec2 / 3600)
    Else
        Dec = (Deg - Min2 / 60 - Sec2 / 3600)
    End If

    ra2decimal = Dec
End Function
```

I'm obviously supplying it three arguements when I run it but its still not happy.

Any ideas?

Comment: ra2decimal? don't understand.

Comment: where and how do you call this function, in excel or in vba editor??

Comment: one more suggestion- check the argument separation characters whether you don't mix them up.

Comment: Seems like I've been an idiot and forgot to change the last ra2decimal to dec2decimal. Thanks all.

Comment: @FergusBarker you may want to upvote those who offered their assistance here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working perfectly fine for me.

Note the revision, change `ra2decimal` to `dec2decimal`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub testDec2Decimal()

MsgBox dec2decimal(1, 1, 1)

End Sub

Public Function dec2decimal(Deg As Integer, Min2 As Integer, Sec2 As Integer) As Double

    Dim Dec As Double
    Dec = 0
    If Deg >= 0 Then
        Dec = (Deg + Min2 / 60 + Sec2 / 3600)
    Else
        Dec = (Deg - Min2 / 60 - Sec2 / 3600)
    End If

    dec2decimal = Dec
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

- are you sure, you are executing the function which you described, is it possible, that another function in another namespace or class is executed?
- are you sure you pass the parameters correctly, their type is correct and their number is correct and they are separated by comma?
- are you sure you didn't make a typo or called the function through a delegate (which is not a problem, but we should know to be able to help you).